# Whenever i run my application, the application crashes and it shows " signal1:Program recieved signal SIGABRT"

Tags: iphone

On the console it shows....

> 2011-09-29 17:06:39.564 Project AddressBook[925:207] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle
>    (loaded)' with name 'eve''
>   *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation
>   0x00e655a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00fb9313 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00e1def8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136   3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00e1de6a +[NSException
>   raise:format:] + 58   4   UIKit
>
>   0x005500fa -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2024  5   UIKit
>
>   0x00551ab7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions)
>   loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168    6   UIKit
>
>   0x00407628 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 70     7
>
>   UIKit                               0x00405134 -[UIViewController
>   loadView] + 120   8   UIKit                               0x0040500e
>   -[UIViewController view] + 56     9   UIKit
>
>   0x00406a3d -[UIViewController viewControllerForRotation] + 63     10 
>   UIKit                               0x00402988 -[UIViewController
>   _visibleView] + 90    11  UIKit                               0x006a493c
>   -[UIClientRotationContext
>   initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 354   12  UIKit
>
>   0x0037c81e -[UIWindow
>   _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] +
>   954   13  UIKit                               0x00604619
>   -[UIWindowController
>   transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:]
>   + 1381    14  UIKit                               0x0040965d
>   -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:withTransition:] + 3478
>     15  Project AddressBook                 0x000032cb -[Home Events:] +
>   155   16  UIKit                               0x003554fd
>   -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119   17  UIKit
>
>   0x003e5799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67  18  UIKit
>
>   0x003e7c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] +
>   527   19  UIKit                               0x003e67d8 -[UIControl
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458    20  UIKit
>
>   0x00379ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567    21  UIKit
>
>   0x0035ac37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447  22  UIKit
>
>   0x0035ff2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576   23  GraphicsServices
>
>   0x01723992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550     24  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00e46944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 52  25  CoreFoundation                      0x00da6cf7
>   __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215    26  CoreFoundation
>   0x00da3f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979   27  CoreFoundation
>   0x00da3840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208     28  CoreFoundation
>   0x00da3761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    29  GraphicsServices
>   0x017221c4 GSEventRunModal + 217  30  GraphicsServices
>   0x01722289 GSEventRun + 115   31  UIKit
>   0x00363c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160   32  Project AddressBook
>   0x00002828 main + 102     33  Project AddressBook
>   0x000027b9 start + 53 ) terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'NSException' sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all Current language: 
>   auto; currently objective

HELP ME PLEASE!!

Comment: and accept some answers.

Answer (score 1):

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', **reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle (loaded)' with name 'eve''**

Your problem is exactly this. You try to load a nib file named 'eve'.

Somewhere you call something like this:

```
VC *aVC = [[[VC alloc] initWithNibName:@"eve" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

Xcode 4 should show you the call stack when it hits that exception. And in the source window it should show you the code where it happened. Three or four lines above that line is your problem.